# Generic error: Runtime compiler is not loaded,

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am creating a directive in VSCode Editor which loads a html page on specifying a given path:

Below is the code for same:

```
@Directive({
 selector: 'html-outlet'
})

export class HtmlOutlet {
 @Input() html: string;

 constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) { 
}

ngOnChanges() {
const html = this.html;
if (!html) return;

@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-comp',
    templateUrl: html
})
class DynamicHtmlComponent { };

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
})
class DynamicHtmlModule { }

this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
    .then(factory => {
        const compFactory = factory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === DynamicHtmlComponent);
        const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0);
    });}}
```

This code used to work perfectly fine untill i upgraded app to angular 6.
I am getting below error now :

Runtime compiler is not loaded Error stack trace: Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
    at Le (main.00612d315fe86075b5fb.js:1)
    at t.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync

Can i get some help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the application in --prod mode it will default to AOT, which doesn't provide the compiler.

I don't think that the Angular team is encouraging the pattern of using the compiler at runtime at all.

Comment: should i turn off AOT in prod mode or change my approach alltogether?

Comment: You can try turning AOT off, but a more sustainable decision will be to re-thing your approach.